# OPC vs SNMP protocol

Tags: networking, network-programming, snmp, opc

Let me start with a full disclosure : I have been given a mission which is out of my leauge and I am 'grasping at straws' here.

the back story :

I have 3 different pieces of hardware . all of them collects the same data but stores it differently .

I wantto make a 4th hardware which will collect the data from all of the others and to do so I first need to choose which protocol is better for this job and implement it on thoose hardwares.

they are not connected to the internet but have a connection between them .

Once in my studies I learnt about SNMP protocol and from googling now I came across OPC protocol .

I can't understand what is the difference between them [as for my understanding both have alarm events , secure ,etc] , and can't find full info about OPC .
trying to understand which one is suited for me.

to clarify I am planning to implement my own version of DB in the hardware [for example on SNMP I will need to build my own MIBs/somekind of my own agent ] .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SNMP is a general purpose protocol which is widely used everywhere to manage/monitor all kinds of equipment, systems, devices and hardware in different domains. Nowadays, it is a de-facto standard  protocol used for monitoring/management of any type of entities. 
In opposite to that the OPC is only used in SCADA domain. So it is kind of specific. I'd go with SNMP if I were you.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that SNMP is a better choice in this case. But the explanation of OPC is strange in my point of view just wrong.

SNMP is designed to monitor devices connected to some sort of network like TCP/IP. Nowadays it is indeed mainly used in network equipment like router etc.

OPC is a protocol to retrieve data, alarms and historical data from a device.
Alarm is in the case of a PLC a real alarm. Like tank 1 is almost overflowing. Action is/must be taken.

OPC is not only used in Scada. It mainly used for software to communicate with PLCs and own written software. That can be SCADA-software, but that is not always the case.

Answer (score 1):

SNMP=Simple Network Management Protocol. According to my experience with it- it is far from being simple. So beware of using it unless you completely sure it addresses your problem best, e.g you have large and complex firmware and software and you need to sync interfaces between various departments of software engineers.
I would propose in simple cases as yours just to implement anything proprietary or use Prometheus which is far simpler and more flexible for changes. 
Good Luck.